# WordPress echo taxonomy of custom post type in wordpress loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a Custom Post Type `product` and for this CPT I've also created a taxonomy with the name `products_types`.

Now on my overview page of all the `products` I would like to echo out the product type that was given to the product. But I keep getting `bool(false)`.

My code:

```
<div class="row">
        <?php
        $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'product') );
        if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                ?>

                <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 work">
                    <div class="category">
                        <?php
                        $category = get_the_terms('product', 'products_types');
                        var_dump($category);
                        echo $category;
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="work-box"> <img src="<?= get_field('image'); ?>" alt="">
                        <div class="overlay">
                            <div class="overlay-caption">
                                <p><?php echo the_title() ?></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <?php
            endwhile;
        endif;
        wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
</div>
```

Anyone can help me out here please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the Post ID or object in first parameter of [`get_the_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/). Used [`get_the_ID()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_ID/) which return the post ID.

Example:

```
foreach (get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'products_types') as $cat) {
   echo $cat->name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**How to print taxonomy terms of custom post type in WordPress loop?**

```
<div class="row">
        <?php
        $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'product') );
        if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                ?>

                <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 work">
                    <div class="category">
                        <?php
                        $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'products_types' );

                        if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) : 

                            $category_links = array();

                            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                                $category_links[] = $term->name;
                            }

                            $categories = join( ", ", $category_links );
                            ?>
                            <?php printf( esc_html( $categories ) ); ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="work-box"> <img src="<?= get_field('image'); ?>" alt="">
                        <div class="overlay">
                            <div class="overlay-caption">
                                <p><?php echo the_title() ?></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <?php
            endwhile;
        endif;
        wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
</div>
```